# Can't Install Anything on Live Installation of Ubuntu

Tags: apt, software-installation, live-usb

I am running a live installation of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with Persistent Storage of 40GB. For some reason I can not install anything without getting the error `Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.` (see full output below). For instance, I am trying to install Keepass2. I have added the repositories `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:jtaylor/keepass`, I have updated apt `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`, and yet when I run `sudo apt-get install keepass2 -y` I still get that same error! I did almost exactly the same process when trying to install i2p, and I also got the broken packages error. I also can not open the Ubuntu Software app.

Full Output of `sudo apt-get install keepass2 -y`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 keepass2 : Depends: mono-runtime (>= 3.0~) but it is not installable
            Depends: libmono-corlib4.5-cil (>= 5.18.0.240) but it is not installable
            Depends: libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil (>= 5.12.0.309) but it is not installable
            Depends: libmono-system-security4.0-cil (>= 5.18.0.240) but it is not installable
            Depends: libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil (>= 5.16.0.220) but it is not installable
            Depends: libmono-system-xml4.0-cil (>= 4.6.1.3) but it is not installable
            Depends: libmono-system4.0-cil (>= 5.18.0.240) but it is not installable
            Recommends: xsel but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Full Output of `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`:

```
[sudo] password for i2p: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

PPAs Installed:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20220831)]/ focal main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/i2p-maintainers-ubuntu-i2p-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/i2p-maintainers/i2p/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/i2p-maintainers-ubuntu-i2p-focal.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/i2p-maintainers/i2p/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/i2p-maintainers-ubuntu-i2p-focal.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/i2p-maintainers/i2p/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/i2p-maintainers-ubuntu-i2p-focal.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/i2p-maintainers/i2p/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/i2p-maintainers-ubuntu-i2p-focal.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/i2p-maintainers/i2p/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/i2p-maintainers-ubuntu-i2p-focal.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/i2p-maintainers/i2p/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jtaylor-ubuntu-keepass-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jtaylor/keepass/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jtaylor-ubuntu-keepass-focal.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jtaylor/keepass/ubuntu focal main
```

Comment: Your package system is broken, it has nothing to do with your install being on a thumb drive. What ppas have you installed?

Comment: deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20220831)]/ focal main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/i2p-maintainers/i2p/ubuntu focal main
(1/2)

Comment: # deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/i2p-maintainers/i2p/ubuntu focal main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/i2p-maintainers/i2p/ubuntu focal main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/i2p-maintainers/i2p/ubuntu focal main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/i2p-maintainers/i2p/ubuntu focal main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/i2p-maintainers/i2p/ubuntu focal main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jtaylor/keepass/ubuntu focal main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jtaylor/keepass/ubuntu focal main
(2/2) @OrganicMarble

Comment: Please put that stuff in your question, it's utterly unreadable in comments.

Comment: Sorry, edited my question. @OrganicMarble

Comment: Since you say " I did almost exactly the same process when trying to install i2p, and I also got the broken packages error." I would imagine the trouble comes from the i2p ppa. If you didn't successfully install i2p, consider removing that ppa and any software that came from it. Synaptic Package Manager can be a big help when working on this kind of problem.

Comment: I removed the i2p ppa as well as the keepass one just to see if maybe I need to reinstall. I also tried sudo snap install keepassxc which did work and successfully install, but the application wont open, even in safe graphics mode. So, I reinstalled the Keepassxc ppa sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phoerious/keepassxc and updated apt. Still got the error Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: With no ppas installed, are you able to install anything? You can't just remove the ppas btw. You have to remove the packages that got installed from them. You can use synaptic to look for orphaned packages if you have removed the ppas.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was my Linux version. Because I was running `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phoerious/keepassxc` it was automatically fetching the latest version, the repository meant for 22.10. To fix the issue I found the old repositories for 20.04 and manually adding them to the software sources through Software & Updates.